# Is there away to create a userform that can use multiple variables to run a search for a row in a excel sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am creating a Userform interface for my team, we want to make our data capture uniformed and easier, one of the things that we want to eliminate duplicate entries, by running a search, currently i am only searching an invoice number, Which is working, However It has been requested that we include multiply Variables, the code I have is as follows
So my Interface looked like:
[image]

and my code for the Invoice lookup is

```
Public Sub Search1()
row_Number = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_Number = row_Number + 1
Item_in_Review1 = Sheets("Source").Range("E" & row_Number)
If Item_in_Review = Userform1.TextBox1.Text Then

> /*send relevant data to Userform3*/

UserForm3.TextBox5 = Sheets("Source").Range("B" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox1 = Sheets("Source").Range("C" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox2 = Sheets("Source").Range("D" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox3 = Sheets("Source").Range("E" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox6 = Sheets("Source").Range("F" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox7 = Sheets("Source").Range("G" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox8 = Sheets("Source").Range("H" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox9 = Sheets("Source").Range("I" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox4 = Sheets("Source").Range("J" & row_Number)
End If

Loop Until Item_in_Review = "" 

End Sub
```

and this works so I decided to try and add the other parameters as well, like this :

```
Public Sub Search1()
row_Number = 0
Do
DoEvents
row_Number = row_Number + 1
Item_in_Review1 = Sheets("Source").Range("E" & row_Number)
Item_in_Review2 = Sheets("Source").Range("B" & row_Number)
Item_in_Review3 = Sheets("Source").Range("I" & row_Number)
If Item_in_Review = Userform1.TextBox1.Text And Item_in_Review2 = Userform1.ComboBox1.Text And Item_in_Review3 = Userform1.ComboBox2.Text Then

UserForm3.TextBox5 = Sheets("Source").Range("B" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox1 = Sheets("Source").Range("C" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox2 = Sheets("Source").Range("D" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox3 = Sheets("Source").Range("E" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox6 = Sheets("Source").Range("F" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox7 = Sheets("Source").Range("G" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox8 = Sheets("Source").Range("H" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox9 = Sheets("Source").Range("I" & row_Number)
UserForm3.TextBox4 = Sheets("Source").Range("J" & row_Number)
End If

Loop Until Item_in_Review = "" And Item_in_Review2 = "" And Item_in_Review3 = ""

End Sub
```

But now I am getting a mismatch error, where am I going wrong?
The Idea is that if Userform1.TextBox1.Text + Userform1.ComboBox1.Text + Userform1.ComboBox2.Text = Range B, E, I respectively that it will populate the next userform with all the relevant data. Can anyone help?

Comment: What did you defined those `Item_in_Review#` as? They should be defined as String, and assign the Value properly. You are assigning a Range to a Textbox.

Comment: I assigned a range as the Search parameter because there will be alot of data to go through to look for, so allocating the Range makes the coding easier. and it works.

Comment: Although it works (VBE has done all conversion using default property), it's not a good practise. Which line is the mismatch and what values are those columns A:J when it happens?